Using Block with the option [draw] in NiceMatrix, in combination with [spanish]{babel} leads to an error
I'm having trouble with NiceTabular and Babel (Spanish). The idea here is to draw a square around the letter 'A'. The draw option in Block doesn't seem to play nice with the [spanish] option in Babel. The MWE provided below leads to an 'Missing $ inserted.'-error. When I change the language in the Babel-option to 'english', it works. If I remove the [draw] option, I obviously don't get the square around the letter 'A', but I won't get the error.
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l}
\Block[draw]{1-1}{A} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX!

It works if you add es-noshorthands in babel options, but I don't know exactly what this implies and if it is the best solution. Anyway, don't use the minimal class.

Your example (with article class) compiles fine on an up-to-date TL2024.

Try \usetikzlibrary{babel}

Thanks @jlab, es-noshorthands does the trick, also in my main project.
